# what does ` time ./AnyExecutable` means in linux or bash script?

Tags: linux

I am new to shell script. I was wondering what does following mean. Why `time` is written.

`time ./AnyExecutable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the man page :

```
       time run the program COMMAND with any given arguments ARG....  When
   COMMAND finishes, time displays information about resources used by
   COMMAND (on the standard error output, by default).  If COMMAND exits
   with non-zero status, time displays a warning message and the exit
   status.
```

Answer (score 0):

The time command tells you how much time running the supplied command takes

See examples here

https://www.lifewire.com/uses-of-command-time-2201083